# Parse REST api client receiving push notifications

Tags: python, parse-platform, push-notification, client

I was wondering if it is possible to have a REST api based Parse client that can receive Push notifications.

In particular, I'm using Python for my "device" code on Raspberry Pi, and I'm using the ParsePy library which is a wrapper on top of the Parse REST api.

It doesn't look like Parse supports receiving Push notifications via the REST api (it explicitly says it doesn't support receiving Push notifications in Javascript, while the REST api section doesn't even talk about receiving push notifications).

If I've overlooked something at receiving push notifications can be achieved in a Python client, any pointers would be totally appreciated.

If it is not supported, is there any plan in the works for a Python client SDK (that would support it)?

Thanks,
Sridhar